# C# 7.2 Memory<T> Could not be found

Tags: c#-7.2

Building a new c# 7.2 project. I have included System.Memory. `Span<T>` compiles fine, but compiler complains that it can't find `Memory<T>`
What am I missing?

Comment: You are not missing that much, an update for System.Memory simply has not been pushed to Nuget yet.  The current version (4.4.0-preview2-25405-01) is 5 months old and does not have it.  Memory<> still has a "we're working on it" comment, last update was 5 days ago.  The joys of agile.  You could wait or download the source from corefx.